# how to resize background of dialog box in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Iam having code in which clicking on button pops up dialogue, and clicking on that goes to another dialog, the background of first dialog has been transparent where as the background of next dialog has been black, is it possible to resize the black background of second dialog, please help me thanks

Comment: if you are talking about this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/FFS5a/6/, the background is black because of the line: themeDialog: 'b'. What do you mean by resize?

Comment: Do you mean resize it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/FFS5a/21/ ?

Comment: yes i need like that only, but when i copied the code and run it is not working

Comment: in html i gave <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
 <link type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


 <!-- NOTE: Script load order is significant! -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
 <script type="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

 <script type="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.js"></script> but the click event for button is not working

Comment: Please suggest some solution